# jQuery target combobox to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am trying to execute a jQuery command to hide a combobox. The HTML is:

```
<table id="system-selector" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <span class="custom-combobox" style="display: inline-block;">
              <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
              <input id="select_system_CB" name="select_system_CB" title="" class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
              <a tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                 <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                 <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
              </a>
            </span>
         </td>
       </tr>
OTHER ROWS HERE.....
```

I am executing this jQuery with no errors or success:

```
jQuery('#system-selector .custom-combobox').hide();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I dont see any problems in your code.. :\  http://jsfiddle.net/k2prm65q/

Comment: Works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vbskzb3/). Have you wrapped your code with `$(document).ready(function() { your code });`?

Comment: check your console and see if you have any errors there. my guess is that you have an error somewhere and it is breaking your script.

Comment: As Regent said, you should add you're script into a $(document).ready(function(){ code }); It means that it will run the script when you're document is ready. This should fix you're error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".custom-combobox").hide(100);
```

this will hide your `<span>` including the following class
this work well as you do it.